# Newbie having trouble with Firefox and IE

Tags: css

I'm brand new to coding and having trouble with the alignment of block elements on my first site.

I'm new enough that I'm not even totally sure how to ask the question, so I'll just put it out there and see what happens:

My site is at: http://sites.psu.edu/humanitiesda/spotlight-public-philosophy-journal/. When I view it in Safari or Chrome the block elements under Team and More line up properly, but when viewed in Firefox or IE, they do not.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

I'd welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please describe how the elements do not line-up?

Comment: Screenshot from Firefox: [link](http://sites.psu.edu/humanitiesda/files/2013/12/in-Firefox.jpg)

Screenshot from Chrome: [link] (http://sites.psu.edu/humanitiesda/files/2013/12/in-Chrome.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the empty useless blocks

```
<p>    <!--Team Member 1--></p>
<p>    <!--Team Member 2--></p>
<p>    <!--Team Member 3--></p>
```

By default, a browser can add some margin/padding to a `<p>` block because it represent a paragraph block, so use it to put a comment is weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>    <!--Team Member 2--></p>
```

These are your problem.  There is no reason to have comments in paragraph tags.